# How can I materialize a string to the actual type?

Tags: c#, expression, mongodb-.net-driver

I am creating a projection variable like this:

```cs
var projection = Builders<Items>.Projection
                            .Include(x => x.Name);
```

The `Include` method takes an expression `Expression<Func<TSource,object>> field`.

What I would like to do is to convert a string parameter named `key` for example to `x.Name`, to be able to dynamically project other fields of `Items` at runtime.

```cs
var key = "Name";
var projection = Builders<Items>.Projection
                         .Include(x => x."key");
```

Comment: I believe that you are using the MongoDB .Net Driver. Just apply `.Include(key)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As written this answer from the comment as the future reference, you can apply

```cs
.Include(key)
```

Provide a `string` value which is the field name.

---

As from [`ProjectDefinition<TDocument>.Include<TDocument>()`](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-csharp-driver/blob/93614cccfa52d34a5807477df614aee6a2beb0a6/src/MongoDB.Driver/ProjectionDefinitionBuilder.cs#L122-L126), it supports with the parameter of `FieldDefinition` type,

```cs
public static ProjectionDefinition<TDocument> Include<TDocument>(this ProjectionDefinition<TDocument> projection, FieldDefinition<TDocument> field)
```

which [`FieldDefinition<TDocument>`](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-csharp-driver/blob/9dbfbaab20fcf6a1aeea72452d582fffb79e0cce/src/MongoDB.Driver/FieldDefinition.cs#L165-L174) would perform an implicit cast from the `string` value.

```cs
public static implicit operator FieldDefinition<TDocument>(string fieldName)
```

Comment: This solution solved my problem, but what about methods that does not accept string parameter like query.SortByDescending(x=>x.Name)?  @yong-shun

Comment: Hi, do you mean you want to do something like this: `query.SortByDescending("name")` but unsuccessful?

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I was trying to do

Comment: Didn't test with real data, perhaps this is what you need. [Demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/28cS98). Require Expression to achieve.

Comment: While would suggest to create another question post for the question you asked as it seems to be another topic.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72809794/how-to-create-an-expression-in-c-sharp-from-string